# array+=value not work in ksh?

Tags: ksh

I read somewhere that ksh's array supports `+=` to append new elements, but I tried it and it doesn't work:

```
[ksh] # arr=(a b c d)
[ksh] # arr+=e
[ksh] # echo ${arr[*]}
ae b c d
[ksh] #
```

Why does `arr[0]` becomes `ae`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add an element to the array, it should be like this:

```
arr+=(e)
```

By doing `arr+=e` , it will add to the 1st element of the array. Its because just the name `arr` points to the 1st element of the array itself:

```
$ arr=(a b c d)
$ echo ${arr[0]}
a
$ echo $arr
a
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `arr+=(e)`. Any simple assignment that doesn't specify an index always refers to the zeroth element.

Note that this is a trivial case and things can get more complicated. `+=` has different behavior for both simple and compound assignment depending on context, and also differs between bash, ksh93, and zsh, so it's easy to become confused.

http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#storing_values

Comment: I found many document online about bash but very little about ksh. :(

Comment: @herik Yes, there aren't many. I'm working on documenting some parts (in the above wiki link), but it is indeed difficult to get information, even on the mailing lists.