# Array+=("string") returns syntax error: '"string"' unexpected on mksh R39

Tags: shell, ksh

In a Korn shell script I declare an array to which I try to add a string:

```
#!/bin/ksh
array=()
array+=("string")
```

When executing the script (either `ksh scriptName` or `./scriptName`) I get

```
./scriptName[3]: syntax error: '"string"' unexpected
```

The version of KSH I have is `@(#)MIRBSD KSH R39 2009/08/01`.

Why do I get this error? I saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563753/array-value-not-work-in-ksh) but this does not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into some documentation for the [`mksh` shell and its history](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh_old.htm), it seems the array append operator does *not* seem to be supported on `R39` but only from `R40` onwards

Quoting some notes from the `R40` changelog:

> `R40`:..The `x+=y` and `x+=(y z)` notations for appending to variables and `(!MKSH_SMALL)` arrays are now supported.
>
> `mksh R40` is a major everything release:
>
> `[tg]` Add `+=` to concatenate scalars and append to arrays

Don't think it was supported on `R39`. Recommend upgrading to `R40` which seems to be supporting a whole lot of features than the one you have.